# GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP and vertex sharing specification

Tags: opengl

Suppose I have a triangle (3 vertices). I add a fourth vertex.I use GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP. Can I specify which two vertices of the original triangle should my new triangle share ?

Answer (score 0):

No. A triangle strip is [always built from the previous two vertices](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives).